# how to have conditions in displaying a text from a text file using c++

Tags: c++, file, text

i have this school project where i have this text file:

```
VIDEO ID        : 1
MOVIE TITLE     : TITANIC
GENRE           : ROMANCE
PRODUCTION      : PARAMOUNT PICTURES
NUMBER OF COPIES: 3
VIDEO ID        : 2
MOVIE TITLE     : IT
GENRE           : HORROR
PRODUCTION      : NEW LINE CINEMA
NUMBER OF COPIES: 0
VIDEO ID        : 3
MOVIE TITLE     : HARRY POTTER
GENRE           : FANTASY
PRODUCTION      : WARNER BROS. PICTURES
NUMBER OF COPIES: 10
```

and the program should display the movie when searched like this:

```
Enter movie ID: 1 //user input
VIDEO ID        : 1
MOVIE TITLE     : TITANIC
GENRE           : ROMANCE
PRODUCTION      : PARAMOUNT PICTURES
NUMBER OF COPIES: 3
AVAILABILITY    : AVAILABLE
```

or this:

```
Enter movie ID: 2 //user input
VIDEO ID        : 2
MOVIE TITLE     : IT
GENRE           : HORROR
PRODUCTION      : NEW LINE CINEMA
NUMBER OF COPIES: 0
AVAILABILITY    : NOT AVAILABLE
```

my problem is that i don't know how to display the availability part where it needs to say 'available' if the number of copies is equal or greater than 1, otherwise it will display 'not available' if it is 0.

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("test.txt");
    string line;
    int find = false;
    string id;

    cout << "Enter movie ID: ";
    cin >> id;
    string idnum = "VIDEO ID    : " + id;
    cout << idnum << endl;

    while (file.good())
    {
        getline(file,line);
        if(line==idnum){
            find=true;
            for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
                    getline(file,line);
                    cout << line << endl;
                 }
            break;
        }
    }
    file.close();

    if(find!=true){
        cout << "Movie Not Found" << endl;
    }
    return 0;}
```

big thanks to anyone who would help :)

Comment: Does the file actually contain the field names, like `VIDEO ID        :` and `MOVIE TITLE     :` ... and even `AVAILABILITY    :`? That seems unnecessary.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes. its in the text file

Comment: Is `AVAILABILITY    : AVAILABLE` already present in the text file or do you have to print that separately to the console? If it is the former, you can just simply print that out without checking the number of copies at all.

Comment: @Ruks no its not present in the text file. the availability part should only display in the program after reading the text file

Comment: @Noran Then please present what's actually in the text file. Add two movie entries so we see how they are stored after eachother too.

Comment: @Noran I added an idea as an answer. Since I'm not 100% what the file format actually is you may need to adjust it slightly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i edited my question to be more clear. the code you added is different though. im sorry. the goal of the problem is to display the details of the movie after searching the id of the video and then check if it is available by the number of its copies

Comment: @Noran Ok, I got lucky then. That was the format I was guessing on when I made the answer below. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo also, to be clear, im not supposed to add a new movie. the program is just for searching whether the movie in the text file it is available or not by considering the number of its copies. thanks

Comment: @Noran It's not adding a new movie. It only uses the `Movie` class to simplify reading and printing. Adding a `class` to read one record at a time is a pretty common technique to do this.

Comment: @Noran Great! You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a `class` to store information about one movie and add a member function to be able to read one movie from an `istream` (like an `ifstream`). Since the file contains the field names too, I'd also add a function to strip that part away. Example:

```
#include <sstream> // std::istringstream

struct Movie {
    int id;
    std::string title;
    std::string genre;
    std::string production;
    int number_of_copies;

    // Read a line and strip away the field name and put the result in an istringstream
    // for further processing.
    std::istringstream strip(std::istream& is) {
        std::istringstream iss;
        std::string line;
        if(std::getline(is, line)) {
            if(line.size() >= 18) iss.str(line.substr(18));
        }
        return iss;
    }

    // A function to read the fields from an istream using the above strip function.
    std::istream& read(std::istream& is) {
        strip(is) >> id;
        std::getline(strip(is), title);
        std::getline(strip(is), genre);
        std::getline(strip(is), production);
        strip(is) >> number_of_copies;
        return is;
    }

    // A function to print the information about one movie
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) {
        os << "VIDEO ID        : " << id << '\n'
           << "MOVIE TITLE     : " << title << '\n'
           << "GENRE           : " << genre << '\n'
           << "PRODUCTION      : " << production << '\n'
           << "NUMBER OF COPIES: " << number_of_copies << '\n'
           << "AVAILABILITY    : "
           // here availability depends on if there are more than zero copies in store
           << (number_of_copies > 0 ? "AVAILABLE" : "NOT AVAILABLE") << '\n';
        return os;
    }
};
```

With that `class` in place, you can read one movie at a time and check if it has the correct `id` and print the movie you find.

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream file("test.txt");

    std::cout << "Enter movie ID: ";
    int id;
    std::cin >> id;

    bool found = false; // bool, not int
    Movie mov;
    while(mov.read(file)) { // loop for as long as a movie can be successfully read
        if(mov.id == id) {
            found = true;
            mov.print(std::cout);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(not found) {
        std::cout << "Movie Not Found\n";
    }
}
```